# What does research refresh do in Tharsis?

Tags: tharsis

In the game Tharsis there is a a research option in the refresh panel. What does it do?

Comment: Be more concrete please

Comment: Well, in research area/panel there is a refresh option, what does it do? (10x :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It re-shuffles the research projects you can access. You can use this option for 1 research point if you don't like the current projects.